# Safely pass a list of objects to a thread that reschedules itself

Tags: java

I have a thread that is responsible for purging old data from a MySQL database. We delete in batches so the db isn't consumed if there's a large purge, so the thread does the purge, waits for a few seconds, and then calls itself again to continue the purge (if there's any records left).

My issue is that we allow people to setup multiple rules for what needs to be purged. In an old system that didn't do anything in batches, we'd simply iterate through each "purge rule" and run the queries.

However, now that we have a system where the thread schedules itself again, I can remove rules from the `ArrayList` anymore, due to a `ConcurrentModificationException`

I have an `ArrayList<QueryParameters>` that we iterate. If there are no records left to purge, we should remove the rule from the list, so that the next time the thread runs it doesn't repeat it.

How can I properly remove the rule from the list but not get the CME? I guess I could a ConcurrentHashMap but I don't want really want to store a key->value.

The code is a plugin to a larger java app, we're using their thread schedulder, just FYI.

I've tried both ways to iterate the arraylist, a for loop and using an iterator

```
public class PurgeTask implements Runnable {

    private Prism plugin;
    private ArrayList<QueryParameters> paramList;
    private int total_records_affected = 0, cycle_rows_affected = 0;
    private int purge_tick_delay;

    /**
     * 
     * @param plugin
     */
    public PurgeTask( Prism plugin, ArrayList<QueryParameters> paramList, int purge_tick_delay ){
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.paramList = paramList;
        this.purge_tick_delay = purge_tick_delay;
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    public void run(){
        if(paramList.size() > 0){
            ActionsQuery aq = new ActionsQuery(plugin);
            // Execute in batches so we don't tie up the db with one massive query
            for (Iterator<QueryParameters> it = paramList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                QueryParameters param = it.next();

                cycle_rows_affected = aq.delete(param);
                plugin.debug("Purge cycle cleared " + cycle_rows_affected + " rows.");
                total_records_affected += cycle_rows_affected;

                // If nothing (or less than the limit) has been deleted this cycle, we need to move on
                if( cycle_rows_affected == 0 || cycle_rows_affected < plugin.getConfig().getInt("prism.purge.records-per-batch") ){

                    // Log final count of cleared records
                    plugin.log("Cleared " + total_records_affected + " rows from the database. Using:" + param.getOriginalCommand() );
                    total_records_affected = 0;

                    // Remove the purge rule from the list so we don't repeat
                    paramList.remove(param);

                } else {

                    // Items we're deleted. Leave params in queue and re-schedule this task
                    plugin.deleteTask = plugin.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLaterAsynchronously(plugin, new PurgeTask( plugin, paramList, purge_tick_delay ), purge_tick_delay);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you iterating over the `ArrayList<PurgeRules>`? Can you post the code?

Comment: Added the code to the post

Comment: Have you tried something? Synchronizing the structure? Adding synchronized methods to modify the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayList` is iterated over by multiple threads that might concurrently modify it. If you don't want your purge tasks to be run concurrently you can synchronize the `ArrayList` access:

```
public void run {
   synchronized(paramList) {
       ...
   }
}
```

If you need concurrency, a better datastructure for this would be a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) that guarantees the integrity of the list while iterating over it, but the remove operation is more costly. Still is more efficient than synchronizing access to the entire list.

Further more, you need to remove the param with the `List.remove()` method: `paramList(remove);`, iterator operations are not supported for `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Also, it's better to use in your `PurgeTask` class a `List` interface, not implementations, it's easier to change the data structure behind the scene.

Comment: Ugh, I was missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: i've updated the code using it.remove() and it works perfectly in my tests, but a user trying the new build saw the following exception: http://pste.me/TsC14 - I just ran a full rebuild of the jar for him just in case, but is it still possible to get the CME error using this it.remove method?

Comment: I've gone with the CopyOnWrite solution because this is only for purge rules that really don't run very often, so efficiency isn't a huge concern. Depending on user settings there may be a max of 10 cycles, if even that, and it only runs each time they start the application which is typically a few times a week. Thanks!